# Spring IoC context configuration for library usage?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I have an application A and a library B.

And correspondingly, the context config files: `a.xml` and `b.xml`. `b.xml` is not complete, it requires `a.xml` to work.

However, I can't just `import b.xml` in `a.xml`, because the path of `b.xml` is not determined. I want some kind of automatic discover to use. (Which maybe similar to  java.util.ServiceLoader.)

Is it possible?

Comment: Your saying the library is not complete without the application?  Isn't that the wrong way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Configuration for library defined beans, and Spring will integrate all @Configuration beans and beans defined in context xmls for main application at last.